# BIRT : How to generate and save a report in PDF format using RE API

Tags: java, jvm, birt

I am working on a project to generate BIRT reports in PDF format. The application is not meant to be a web application. I tried to follow the Report Engine API example on this link http://wiki.eclipse.org/Simple_Execute_(BIRT)_2.1 but I get an error when I run (Run as -> Java Application)  the code. My code is as below.

My code is as follows:

```
package birt.classicmodels.offices;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineConfig;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportEngine;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportEngineFactory;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportRunnable;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRunAndRenderTask;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.PDFRenderOption;

public class ExecuteReport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecuteReport er = new ExecuteReport();
        try {
            er.executeReport();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    public void executeReport() throws EngineException {
       IReportEngine engine = null;
       EngineConfig config = null;
       IReportEngineFactory factory = null;
       Object factoryObj = null;
       try {
            config = new EngineConfig();
            config.setBIRTHome("C:\\birt-runtime-4.6.0-20160607\\ReportEngine");
            config.setLogConfig("C:\\temp\\test", Level.FINEST);
            Platform.startup(config);
            factoryObj = Platform.createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
            factory = (IReportEngineFactory) factoryObj;
            engine = factory.createReportEngine(config);      

            // Open the report design
            IReportRunnable design = null;
            String designPath = "C:\\birt-runtime-4.6.0-20160607\\ReportEngine\\samples\\hello_world.rptdesign";
            design = engine.openReportDesign(designPath);
            IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);      

            PDFRenderOption PDF_OPTIONS = new PDFRenderOption();
            PDF_OPTIONS.setOutputFileName("C:\\temp\\test.pdf");
            PDF_OPTIONS.setOutputFormat("pdf");

            task.setRenderOption(PDF_OPTIONS);
            task.run();
            task.close();
            engine.destroy();
        } catch(final Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Platform.shutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

SETUP:

1. I installed the BIRT designer using the complete BIRT designer download.
2. I added all the .jars under the libs folder of the BIRT runtime folder to my build path.
3. The main method was not part of the example I added it with the intention of getting the report saved to my file system.
4. The design template I'm referencing is the design example that comes with the BIRT engine.

ISSUES:

When I run the code (Run as -> Java Application) I get the following errors:

1. A pop up dialog with the message:

```
Java Virtual Machine Launcher
Error: A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again
```

2. After I click OK on the message dialog, the console is populated with the following error:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
   org/eclipse/birt/core/framework/PlatformConfig
   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
   org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.PlatformConfig
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0-20160607</version>
</dependency>
```